# Django: accessing session variables from within a template?

Tags: django

If I set a session variable in Django, like:

```
request.session["name"] = "name"
```

Is there a way I can access it from within a template, or do I have to retrieve it from within a view, and then pass it to a template?

Asking because I have around 10 little session variables that I'd like to access within a template, and passing all 10 from the view to the template could get a bit messy.

(I have to use session variables because it's a HttpResponseRedirect, but storing the variables in a database is overkill for my purposes.)

So - any way to grab session variables directly within a template?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

You need to add [`django.template.context_processors.request`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request) to your [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS). Then you can access them like this:

```
{{ request.session.name }}
```

In case you are using custom views make sure you are passing a RequestContext instance. Example taken from [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1):

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Update 2013:** Judging by the upvotes I'm still receiving for this answer, people are still finding it helpful, more than three years after it was originally written. Please note however, that although the view code above is still valid, nowadays there is a much simpler way of doing this. [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/) is a function very similar to `render_to_response()`, but it uses `RequestContext` automatically, without a need to pass it explicitly:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', my_data_dictionary)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246725/django-template-context-processors#answer-9233283 for how to add django.core.context_processors.request to your template context processors without overriding the defaults.

Comment: if i use HttpResponse instead of render will i still be able to get the session attribute in my template.I am confused please tell me

Comment: @cafebabe1991 What do you mean? The `HttpResponse` class doesn't deal with templates at all, so the question doesn't seem relevant...

Comment: Ya, actually i did an experiment to realise that at the end.Bad question . sorry

Answer (score 28):

`request.session` is a dictionary like any other, so you just use the normal template mechanism for attributes and members:

```
{{ request.session.name }}
```

Don't forget to pass the request into the template context, or even better ensure you are using RequestContext and have the request context processor enabled. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context).

Answer (score 14):

I am using Django 1.9 (March 2016) and to get `{{ request.session.name}}` to work, my settings have this::

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The difference from the previous answers is: `'django.core.context_processors.request'` became `'django.template.context_processors.request'`

Comment: in Django 1.10, the `django.template.context_processors.request` was already in the setting file :D

Answer (score 10):

You can pass a `request` variable to a template and there use:

```
{{ request.session.name }}
```

Answer (score 9):

the simplest implementation is using if loop :

```
{% if 'data' in request.session %}
```

Comment: This is a great answer! It saves you from any redundant lines in the log file.

Answer (score 3):

First print `request.session.keys()` then

```
request.session['_auth_user_id']
request.session['_auth_user_backend']
```

You will get these two session variables.

Answer (score 2):

In your settins.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'
)
```

Your view, maybe look like this.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext

@login_required()
def index_admin(request):
    return render_to_response('carteras/index_admin.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I also had to add 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing @Ludwik Trammer answer, How to add TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

For django 1.6, in settings.py add TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS referring the below code and then use `{{ request.session.name }}` in template files.

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"django.core.context_processors.request")
```

Reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

Pls note that, you should use that complete code in settings. Using `"django.core.context_processors.request"` alone will result in overriding the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit too late now. If you directly set `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `settings.py`, you will lose all default `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` value. Here is what I do in my `settings.py`:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**

### This answer is for those using Django 3.0 and above

**

You don't need to pass the session variables from the views as the sessions are stored in django_sessions table in your database. So just use `return redirect('/')`to simulate passing none without errors.

In index.html file:

- If there's only single data in the session variable, use

  `{{ request.session.your_session_varaible_name }}`
- If you have multiple data in the session variable like a list, it can be accessed by

```html
{% if 'cart_prod' in request.session %} {% for cart_products in request.session.cart_prod %}
<tr>
  <td style="padding: 25px">
    {{ cart_products }}
  </td>
  <tr>
    {% endfor %} {% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

{{ request.session.name_of_session_key }}