# Make redirect url work with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I want to know how can i make my request work with ajax in my views, while i want to redirect user to other page. I mean for example, when user sends his/her email successfully and I want to redirect him/her to other page. What should I do to make this request work with ajax?

I have this function in views.py:

```
def compose(request, recipient=None, success_url=None, recipient_filter=None):
    if request.is_ajax():         
        if request.method == "POST":
            sender = request.user
            form = compose_form(request.POST, recipient_filter=recipient_filter)
            if form.is_valid():
               // do some processing
               if success_url is None:
                   success_url = reverse('messages_inbox')
               if request.GET.has_key('next'):
                   success_url = request.GET['next']
               return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
    else: //rest of function
```

And I check in, for example 'messages_inbox', the request to be passed with ajax. so what's the way?

Answer (score 1):

The view is not the one that should redirect in case of an ajax request. Rather make the view return the `success_url` to the ajax call and then use the success callback to re-direct the user.

Example with jquery

```
$.ajax(url, data, function (data, response, xhr){
    ...
    var url = success_url; //Get success url from your data which is a json response object   
    $(location).attr('href',url);
});
```

You can do redirection without jquery as well, see
[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Then how will we get access to session variable or the request attribute in that page as view did not render the response.

Comment: The existing session/request attribute would already have been available in the page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551933/django-accessing-session-variables-from-within-a-template. If you want the session information from the redirected request, the `response` in the callback function of ajax would have headers that you can access for session related information.

Comment: But in the question you mentioned the link for ..it uses render to response.. And can you show how to retrieve info from headers

Comment: Check `getAllResponseHeaders()` in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and make sure you understand CORS if it is relevant to your situation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie