# django how to store an object in session to use in multiple templates

Tags: django, templates, session, view, request

Im working with django and i would like to store a object (in session?) so i can use this in multiple templates. So similar to the "user" that is always accessible, id like to add one of my own. So i dont have to add it every time in render(request,

What i try so far:

```
def login_character(request, character_name):
    request.session['character'] = Character.objects.get(name=character_name)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Template:

```
{% if 'character' in request.session %}
    <p>Jeej there is some character</p>
    {{ request.session.character.name }}
{% else %}
    <p>Nope, nothing here</p>
{% endif %}
```

But that doesn't seem to work, 
Can someone help me out or point in the right direction?

With kind regards,
Hans

Comment: I recommend reading a little about sessions and [how to use them in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant

```
{% if 'character' in request.session %}
```

instead of

```
{% if 'character' in request.session['character'] %}
```

Also, you wrote that you need sessions, because you want an object to be always accessible, without a need to explicitly add it in every view. In this case I think a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) would probably be a better choice.

---

**Update:** You also need to make sure that [`django.core.context_processors.request`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) is among [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) in your settings file. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551976/262618).

Comment: My mistkae that should bene removed indeed. But it doesnt solve my first problem. It always get to the else statement even if its true (use the terminal with prints to check)

Comment: Is `django.core.context_processors.request` among your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

Comment: Ghehe you the man, got the whole list, but that one was missing :)