# my marketing_message is displayed only in index.html and rest of the pages middleware dont display marketing messages

Tags: django, middleware

I think since i am adding marketing_message in templates of views.py thats why my context is displaying message only at index.py...
i want to display my message in every page of my app.

middleware.py

from .models import MarketingMessage
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

```
class DisplayMarketing(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    def process_request(self, request):
        print("something")
        try:
            request.session['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0].message
        except:
            request.session['marketing_message']  = False
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'marketing.middleware.DisplayMarketing',
]
```

added it in views.py

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    marketing_message = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0]
    context = {'products':products,'marketing_message':marketing_message}
    return render(request,'pro/index.html',context)
```

base.html

```
{% if marketing_message %}
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible alert-top-message" role="alert">
    <h3>
    {{ marketing_message.message|safe }}
  </h3>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

index.html--

```
{% extends "pro/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block head_title %}
Home||
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
      {% if product.productimage_set.all %}
        {% for item in product.productimage_set.all %}
          {% if item.featured %}
          <div style="width:200px;
                      height:200px;
                      background-image:URL('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image.url }}');
                      background-repeat:no-repeat;
                      background-size: cover;
                      background-position:center;
                      margin:0 auto;">

          </div>
          <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image.url }}" > -->
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        <img src="{% static '/download.svg' %}" class="img-responsive" />
      {% endif %}
        <div class="caption">
          <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}"><h3>{{ product.title }}</h3></a>
          <p>{{ product.description|truncatewords:15 }}</p>
          <p><a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: in base html request.session.marketing_message.message or request.session.marketing_message

Comment: @giveJob sir i tried this but still the message only appears in index.html only

Comment: show index.html in question may be your not inherting template properly from base.html

Comment: @giveJob i added index

Comment: and what is this MarketingMessage.objects.get()

Comment: sorry its all()..i was trying something diffirent so i did that and forgot to remove from there

Answer (score 0):

This means you either have to pass the marketing message on every view.

Or you could also [create a custom templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def marketing_message():
     return MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0]
```

And then load the tag in the `html` and display the result.

EDIT:

To have the message on every page either you include the message in your `base.html` and extend the other templates from base
or you have to import and use the templatetag in every template

EDIT 2: Usage in `base.html`

Assuming the above code is in `poll_extra.py` and you have the following structure where `polls` your apps name is

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        poll_extras.py
    views.py
```

the `base.html` needs:

```
{% load poll_extras %}
{% marketing_message %}
```

the first line loads the tag(s) and the second is the tag which returns the message, it is called by the name of the python function

this is all described in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)

Edit: using Middleware
from the [documentation about middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware)

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.

    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.

    return response
```

then your middleware should adjust the context of the response after (or before, not sure if it matters in your case) the view is called

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551976/13168118)  maybe you try to access the value the wrong way?

Comment: what is not working? whats the behavior of it? can you describe more?

Comment: i want to my marketing_message to be displayed on each page.But it is only visible at index page..

Comment: you have to use the templatetag on every page / or in your `base.html` and extend the other templates from base

Comment: and what i need to include as template tag to my base.html??

Comment: i adjusted my answer

Comment: u r correct sir it satisfy my requirement but i need to use middleware and middle ware dont use custom template tag like this