# Passing request.user to template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Is there another way to get the request.user by not passing it from the views? I think passing request.user from all functions in views to the template is quite wrong. Is there any method or way that the template will get the user or any object in the database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default (I am talking about Django version 1.3) you do not need change TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Because [default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) already contains *django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth*.

So to your question: By default, you should be able to use *user*, *messages* and *perms* variables in your template. For example:

```
User: {{user.username}}
{% if perms.appname.permname %}
  ... do something usefull ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: ow, i see. sorry I'm a noob. How bout an object in the database? Is there a way that the template can get it?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by _object in the database_. If you have model (class in your model.py) and want to display it, you can use [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#list-detail-generic-views).

Comment: I have this model called SchoolSetting and It always contains 1 or more objects. I want to get the first object (SchoolSetting.objects.all()[0]) and put it in the default values of template_context_processors

Comment: nevermind, got it already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246725/django-template-context-processors

Comment: If you want to get only one object from database, you should use SchoolSetting.objects.get(pk=X), where X is ID of desired object.

Answer (score 0):

[Context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).