# Passing an object in every Django page

Tags: django, templates

I have an object called `Groups` that is used in every single page on my website. However, Django only passes in Python objects to html through `render_to_response` and I can't render to response everytime something happens to the groups object.

How do I maintain this object(as in make it respond to adding and deletion) and produce it in every Django template that I have without calling `render_to_response`?

Answer (score 7):

write a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

```
#my_context_processors.py

def include_groups(request):
    #perform your logic to create your list of groups
    groups = []
    return {'groups':groups}
```

then add it in your settings file:

```
#settings.py

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     "django.core.context_processors.auth",
     "django.core.context_processors.debug",
     "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
     "django.core.context_processors.media",
     "path.to.my_context_processors.include_groups",
)
```

now a variable `groups` will be available to you in all your templates

Answer (score 1):

If you need data added to more than one template contexts you should look into achieving that via your own [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create template context processor to pass an object to each request. Here is some [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246725/django-template-context-processors)

Answer (score 0):

```
#tu_context_processor.py

from setting.models import Business


def include_business(request):
    business = Business.objects.all().last()
    return {'business': business}
```

in your settings file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'core.tu_context_processor.include_business',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

now a variable business will be available to you in all your templates
tested in Django 4