# Django admin template: Accessing request object in template

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-1.2

I need the request object in all admin templates. In frontend templates, I can achieve this by rendering the template with `RequestContext`:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
    my_data_dictionary,
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

With that, I can access the request object in frontend:

```
{{ request.path }}
```

How can I do this for all admin views in Django 1.2?

Comment: Did you add `request` `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The request should be available in the admin templates if you have `'django.core.context_processors.request'` added to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your `settings.py`

Comment: should this only be needed to access `request`-properties within **admin-templates**? using django 1.5 in combination with `django.shortcuts.render` which should implicitly include request it appears that this is needed for own (non-admin) views as well. can you confirm or even explain? (btw, i'm fairly new to django so might oversee/misunderstand simple things...)

Comment: an older [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2551976/294930) suggests adding `'django.core.context_processors.request'` also for general access to request properties (the session-dict in the linked example)...
btw, this [hint showing how to append values within settings instead of overwriting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9233283/294930) also seems worth mentioning in this context ;)