# no TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in django

Tags: django, django-settings, django-1.6

I don't have `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`  in my default settings!

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

Do I have to add it myself What do I do? Please give me your suggestion or advice. Thank you!

Comment: I think that this is the best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9233283/888245

Answer (score 12):

In Django 1.7 and later versions, context_processor can be configured for each template backend engine and is available under **TEMPLATES** setting variable in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs these seems to be the default, unless you overide it.
[link to doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)

Comment: So, that means I don't have to add `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in the settings, right?

Comment: right, but you could add it as well, if you plan to add more processors, so you don't override the default.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.6 brings a cleanest settings.py file. Now a lot of default settings are omited and you just need override it whether you need.