# Django - using my context in render_to_response

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Is there a way to call all my user data? without using all the template variables in my views

**Templates:**

```
 {% csrf_token %}
 <h1>Welcome {{user.full_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h1>
 <h1>{{user.email}}</h1>
```

so in my views I'll use less code, by not declaring all the dict

**views**

```
return render_to_response('user/userhome.html', user)
```

Comment: found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246725/django-template-context-processors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For django version 1.8 or more you can directly access {{user}} in template. However you can add the following in the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR of your settings to access {{user}} directly in the template.

```
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict-like object that defines `__contains__` and `__getitem__`, but uses attribute access to set properties, eg.:

```
from django import shortcuts, template
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class Page(dict):
    # see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute-in-python
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Page, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

@login_required
def foo(request):
    page = Page()
    page.user = request.user
    return shortcuts.render_to_response('foo.html', page)
```

then you can write your template exactly the way you would like.