# How would you setup a "context" type object in django

Tags: python, django

In Rails if I want to setup a "context" which is basically objects that every view will need like the user object for a logged in user, or say a store/account/location object, how would I have this available on every view in the django framework?

In Rails I would do something like this:

```
class BaseController
  before_action :setup_context


  def setup_user
   @user = # load user from db
   @location = # load location for user
  end
end

class HomeController < BaseController

  def index
    # I now can use the variables @user and @location
  end

end
```

Does Django have these types of events that I can load objects and use them in all my views?

Comment: Is it only `user` that you need to access? If so then `request.user` is the object to access for view methods.

Comment: @ShangWang no not user, I usually do:  context.user context.location context.account   i.e. everything added to a context object.

Comment: This is what context processors are for, see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893724/creating-my-own-context-processor-in-django or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246725/django-template-context-processors - specifically that's how Django adds the `user` object to the request, and you can write your own if you need more than the built in ones provide.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own context processor:

**Study :**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/

Comment: This. There is tremendous power in having your own context processor, and it greatly simplifies passing all manner of "global state" into your templates.

Comment: Yes, it is really powerful

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're trying to do something like this. I'm still fairly inexperienced with Django myself, so take this with a grain of salt.

Basic example:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from exampleapp.models import User  # User object defined in your models.py

def index(request):
    context = { 'users': User.objects.all() }
    return render(request, 'exampleapp/example.html', context)
```

example.html

```
{% if users %}
    {% for user in users %}
        <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No users.</p>
{% endif %}
```

My apologies if I've missed the mark on your question.

Comment: I was finding this. Thank you!