# How to create correct path in Django template

Tags: django, templates

I'm trying to create menu in template which leads to some subpages:

```
<a href="/">HOME</a> <a href="/about/">O NAS</a> <a href="/rules/">REGULAMIN</a> <a href="/faq/">FAQ</a> <a href="/docs/">DOKUMENTY</A> <a href="/contact/">KONTAKT</a>
```

And it works only when I put it into main folder, so the url is `http://example.org/about/`.

When I put it into some subfolder it goes wrong:

`http://example.org/subfolder/about/` works, but links in menu leads still `http://example.org/about/` which is correct behaviour.

relative path is not working, because it adds instead of replacing last part of URL e.g.: `http://example.org/subfolder/about/rules/`.

If I would know what url it would be placed, I can hardcode it into template, but I'm sure that it will work in two places with different "subfolders", and I want to make it working in any environment.

I'm trying to find solution, but it leads me to  `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` which isn't working for me, and i'm not sure if it is exactly what I'm trying to get, so I don't dive to deep into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

into settings.py

This was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233283/354420

In template you can use `views.about` or `name` if defined.

Answer (score 1):

[Name your URL's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

```
url(r'^about', views.about, name="about")
```

Then use the [URL template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to generate the appropriate URL for each name.

```
{% url 'about' %}
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'about' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []